# Inconsistencies in calculating exhaust velocity

Tags: engine-design, physics, calculation, exhaust

I'm quite sure this is either a small or just plain stupid mistake but my anxiety is getting the better of me. when calculating exhaust velocity this is the equation used:

[image]

however I keep getting higher values than that listed, specifically on [Astronautix](http://www.astronautix.com/h/h2o2.html#:%7E:text=Temperature%20of%20Combustion%3A%201%2C165%20deg,%3A%20H2O2%2D90%25%20monopropellant.). I should mention I am solving for monopropellant HTP-85%, where $M = 20.7 kg$, $k = 1.34$, $P_c = 10\ bar$, $P_e = 1\ bar$, $T_c = 910\ K$ and $R$ is the universal gas constant. I suspect that it is just the difference between theoretical and actual performance however $1128\ m \cdot s^{-1}$ is very different from $~900\ m \cdot s^{-1}$. Is there something I am missing or am I just using the formula in the wrong context?

Comment: The formula assumes that the exhaust is an ideal gas, which it is not.

Comment: Related (deleted) question: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/59232/30164

Comment: @fasterthanlight thank you very much is there another formula/means of correction?

Comment: Please remember that Pe *is not the ambient pressure, it is the exit plane pressure* 1 bar Pe would be a terrible underexpanded booster engine design.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I understand this is the case with actual boosters which have to optimise for a large envelope but this nozzle is merely designed for sea level use

Comment: It's still the wrong equation. See my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are simply calculating the wrong parameter.

You are calculating *exhaust velocity*. You can't calculate this without knowledge of the nozzle geometry because exit plane pressure is used in the calculation. Hence my comment about you picking exit plane pressure = 1 bar - that means you have assumed a nozzle geometry, and a very poor one for a booster engine at that.

The Astronautix page is giving *[characteristic velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_velocity)*.  That is primarily a function of the gas properties in the combustion chamber and therefore does not depend on the nozzle geometry.

[image: formula for characteristic velocity]

Reference: Mechanics and Thermodynamics of Propulsion, Hill and Peterson, 1970, p. 357

[image: formula for characteristic velocity]

Reference: Rocket Propulsion Elements, Sutton, 1976, p. 72

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't tell you how useful this has been; I hadn't realised there was a distinction! Thank you for the quick response